# AngularJS and Rails templets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

How can I combine Rails and AngularJS templets  without gems. Is that possible at all? If it is in with folder should I add angular and templets and what I need to do with routes?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?

Comment: I want to make main AngularJS html page as partial so I can incorporate in rails views